# Join to same table twice only if second record exists

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a select query that joins to the same table twice IF there are two distinct records in the joined table, and returns null if it does not.  It is something like this:

```
SELECT t1.title, t3a.name, t3b.name
from t1
join t2a on t1.id = t2a.id
join t2b on t1.id = t2b.id
join t3a on t2a.xid = t3a.xid
join t3b on t2b.xid = t3b.xid
```

I'll leave out all the permutations of join types and where statement qualifiers I've tried (none have worked) but the gist is this:

t1 always has at least one corresponding record relationship in t2->t3, and sometimes two.  I'd like my results to be:

```
Title | Related Record 1 | Related Record 2 (if exists)
```

What I'm getting is SOMETIMES what I want, but more often it's

```
Title | Related Record 1 | Related Record 1
```

And this happens whether or not there are two distinct related recordsets in t2/t3.  But in the same query sometimes the distinct records will return and sometimes the first result will repeat twice.

Does that make sense?  I apologize for the elementary nature of my question :-)

Comment: since you say you want to join to the same table twice, are `t1, t2a, t2b, t3a, and t3b` aliases for the same table?

Comment: jayoaK - thanks for responding.  Table 1 = t1.  Table 2 = t2a and t2b.  Table 3 = t3a and t3b.  3 tables total.  Table 2 exists as an in-between table that links the entity in Table 1 to the attribute(s) in Table 3.

Comment: It's much easier to answer questions like this if you post some sample data, the desired output from that data, and don't use table names like t1, t2a, t3a, t3b but instead use realistic names. A vague rambling description of what you're trying to accomplish means we have to spend time trying to clarify what you're asking in the first place before we can even try to help find a solution. If you want help, it's to your advantage to make the question clear and provide the pertinent details. You're asking us for *free help* to solve *your problem*; you should make it as easy as possible for us.

Comment: Thank you Ken, duly noted.  It's the first question I've asked on here; I've seen the t1/t2 pseudo on here before so I thought that might be preferred. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question and comments correctly, the query really is:

```
select t1.title, t3a.name, t3b.name
from t1 join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.id = t2a.id join
     t2 t2b
     on t1.id = t2b.id join
     t3 t3a
     on t2a.xid = t3a.xid join
     t3 t3b
     on t2b.xid = t3b.xid;
```

I see no value to joining to the same tables twice with the same `join` conditions, so I suspect that you get the same results (perhaps with fewer duplicates) using:

```
select t1.title, t3.name
from t1 join
     t2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     t3 t3
     on t2.xid = t3.xid;
```

If there are multiple matches, then these will appear on different rows.  To bring them on one row, you can use aggregation:

```
select t1.title, min(t3.name) as name1,
       (case when min(t3.name) <> max(t3.name) then max(t3.name) end) as name2
from t1 join
     t2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     t3 t3
     on t2.xid = t3.xid
group by t1.title
```

The conditional just makes the third column `NULL` if there is only one name.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  You understood my poorly-worded question perfectly, and eliminating the second join and adding the conditional and the grouping indeed did exactly what I wanted.  Thank you very much for your assistance.